# Angular 4 get function return value afrer http post request

Tags: angular, typescript, post, recaptcha, dataservice

I created a controller method that sends a captcha response to google server after solving a reCaptcha and the request returns a captcha response JSON. Controller method returns `true` if captcha response is `=="success"`, else it returns `false`.

The request is sent with http POST, but the problem I'm facing is: how do I get the  boolean value from controller method after receiving a resposne after POST request?

**Controller method**:

```
 {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            bool success = false;

            var client = new System.Net.WebClient();

            string PrivateKey = "6LeiumYUAAAAAMS0kU0OYXaDK0BxHO7KJqx2zO7l";

            var GoogleReply = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}", PrivateKey, Model.RecaptchaResponse));

            var captchaResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReCaptchaController>(GoogleReply);

            success = captchaResponse.Success.ToLower() == "true" ? true : false;

            return Ok(success);
        }

        return BadRequest();

    }

    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public string Success
    {
        get { return m_Success; }
        set { m_Success = value; }
    }

    private string m_Success;
    [JsonProperty("error-codes")]
    public List<string> ErrorCodes
    {
        get { return m_ErrorCodes; }
        set { m_ErrorCodes = value; }
    }

    private List<string> m_ErrorCodes;
}
```

**POST request in DataService**:

```
//Http Post request for server-side reCAPTCHA validation
checkRecaptcha(url: string, data: Object): Observable<boolean> {
    this.timerService.resetTimer();
    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data), this.sharedService.getRequestHeaders())
        .map((response: Response) => {
            return response.json() as boolean
        })
        .catch((response: Response) => {
            return Observable.throw(response);
        });
}
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
resolved(captchaResponse: string) {
    let data = {
        RecaptchaResponse: captchaResponse
    };
    let result = this.dataService.checkRecaptcha('api/recaptcha/validate', data);
    console.log(result);
}
```

In chrome debug I get an Observable: http://prntscr.com/ke5eeo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `return response.json() as boolean` returns for the observable, not for your `checkRecaptcha` function. You will need to listen to your own `checkRecaptcha`'s returned Observable:

```
this.dataService.checkRecaptcha('api/recaptcha/validate', data).subscribe(
  (result: boolean) => console.log(result)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe the observable...

```
checkRecaptcha(url: string, data: Object): Observable<boolean> {
    this.timerService.resetTimer();
    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data), this.sharedService.getRequestHeaders());
}
```

afterwards you should be able to call the Service and Subscribe to its results:

```
this.dataService.checkRecaptcha('api/recaptcha/validate', data).subscribe((result) => {
   console.log(result);
});
```